# kendo ui grid check record if null on databound

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there anyway i could check if the kendo ui grid has record on databoud?,

The following code will throw an error if the record is empty since i try to modified the edit button

```
function GridOnDataBound(e)
    {
        var innerContent = $(".k-grid-delete").html().replace("Delete", "");
                            $(".k-grid-delete").html(innerContent);

          var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');   
         if(grid != null)
          {
         var innerContentEdit= $(".k-grid-edit").html().replace("Edit", "");
                                    $(".k-grid-edit").html(innerContentEdit);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a `databound` event handler, you can simply use `this.dataSource.total() === 0` to check for items.

There's also an example on how to customize the default edit button [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.command.text).

Answer (score 1):

```
var noData = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data().length() == 0;
```

This will tell you if you have some data in your datasource. Eitherway I would suggest to use template for what you doing and do the replace in the template.

Comment: Either you can try 

 $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.view().length